# How to let users draw a circle on google map in android using touch event?

Tags: google-maps, android-widget, android-mapview, android

I have been working on an android application where I need to get radius as input from users. I have been searching for a way (with no luck) to let users draw a circle (maybe a polygon too) on goolge map like this application does on ipad

http://itunes.apple.com/us/app/realtor.com-real-estate-search/id336698281?mt=8

and somehow find the coordinates bounded by the circle or polygon.

Is there a way to even draw on google map on android using touch event? If yes then how do I get all the points in inside the polygon?

Any help would be appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

You could put the `MapView` in a `FrameLayout`, and overlay it with another View by placing that View in the same FrameLayout. This other View could capture the touch events, and you could put your drawing code on that layer.

Comment: And how do I get the geo coordinates and other information about the points inside the polygon?

Comment: You can pass the touch event through both Views. Just return false from onTouch in your drawing layer: http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.OnTouchListener.html#onTouch(android.view.View, android.view.MotionEvent)